# titlesec makes fancyhdr mistreating the document class

Tags: fancyhdr, titlesec, article

MWE is pretty simple:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\section{tist1}
\subsection{a}
\newpage
\subsection{b}
\end{document}
```

On the second page, there is the subsection name on the left and the section name on the right.

Now, uncomment the `titlesec` import, and the behaviour changes: the section name on the left and nothing (actually, a fantom of non-existent chapter name) on the right.

It happens because `titlesec` redefines `\chapter` as `\relax`, though normally it's `undefined` in `article` class. The `fancyhdr` packages has a following check:

```
\ifx\chapter\@undefined
```

It fails, and marks are defined as in classes that have chapters. I can work it around with

```
\let\chapter\undefined
```

after `\usepackage{titlesec}`, or by explicitly redefining `sectionmark`/`subsectionmark` after `\pagestyle{fancy}`. But why should I? Is this a bug in `titlesec`, or setting `\chapter` to `\relax` has some purpose?

**UPD:**

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
titlesec.sty    2016/03/21 v2.10.2 Sectioning titles
fancyhdr.sty    2017/06/30 v3.9a Extensive control of page headers and footers
 ***********
```

Comment: What versions of the packages are you using? (Put `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and report the output here.) I get identical output with or without `titlesec`.

Comment: @AlanMunn added to the post.

Comment: Update `fancyhdr`; the current version is 2019/01/31 v3.10

Comment: @egreg yes, the new version of `fancyhdr` has a `\f@nch@ifundefined` macro which handles both `undefined` and `\relax`, thanks. But anyway, is there any purpose to set `\chapter` to `\relax` instead of `undefined` in `titlesec`?

Comment: @bodqhrohro That should be asked to the package maintainer.